# Unable to login to email server that I can telnet to?

Tags: mysql, postfix, dovecot, password, thunderbird

I just finished following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin) on Digital Ocean for configuring a Dovecot, MySQL, and Postfix email server. I did not follow it to the end. (I didn't install Spam Assassin.) I also used a self-generated SSL temporarily. Other than that, I followed the tutorial to the letter. At every point where I was told to do a test command, I did so and the results were what the author said they should be.

The problem is that using an email client (like Thunderbird) I cannot login to the server. However, using Telnet I can connect to SMTP on ports 587 and 25. I can also connect to IMAP on port 993. (25, 587, and 993 are the ONLY ports I have forwarded from my external IP.)

I have checked the data in the MySQL DB. My user exists with my desired password.

How can I troubleshoot the issue here? Is there a way to test login credentials using telnet?

**EDIT**

Authentication is the issue. I've initiated the connection with `openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:587 -starttls smtp` (Thanks 84104). My exchange then looks like this...

```
ehlo example.com
250-hostname.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
MyBase64EncodedUsername
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
MyBase64EncodedPassword
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: Connection lost to authentication server
```

Is there a debugging route I can take to find the problem? Is this simply authentication or a connection issue?

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: By going through the logs I was able to find an error which solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes` means that telnet isn't going to be a viable option for credential testing. You really don't want to do the TLS negotiation by hand.

Instead use something like [`openssl s_client`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/s_client), e.g. `openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:587 -starttls smtp`.

Once connected you can then issue the standard commands. The exchange should look similar too:

```
S> Blah...Blah...Blah...
S> ---
S> 250 DSN
C> ehlo <client hostname>
S> 250-<server hostname>
S> Blah...Blah...
S> 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
S> Blah...Blah...
S> 250 DSN
C> auth plain <echo -ne '\0<username>\0password>' | base64>
S> 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Is there a way to login with credentials?

Comment: @Allenph The same way you would had you been using telnet. I've added an example exchange.

Comment: I attempted to login...authentication is the problem. I did it a little differently than you, though. I logged in, issued `ehlo  example.com`, then `AUTH LOGIN` then used Perl to give me the Base64 encoded version of my username and password. I then entered my username, entered, then my password. Authentication failed. I noticed that the author of that tutorial uses SHA2. Does that have something to do with it? How can I debug the setup?

Comment: I've expanded my question with an example of my exchange after logging in to SMTP.